# Woocommerce plugin for random group of products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a wordpress plugin for allowing users to create random groups of products based on their selection?

For example I can create my own set of fairy lights/ lamps on this page

http://cableandcotton.co.uk/shop/choose-your-own#length=35&colours=show

Comment: If you mean can you make a product that is customizable then yes, you can do that with [WooCommerce Composite Products](http://www.woothemes.com/products/composite-products/). Otherwise, you should rephrase your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use

`https://wordpress.org/plugins/ect-product-carousel/`

or

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/splendid-product-viewer/
```

Hope this will help you